# Reduce linespread between \item globally

Tags: spacing, lists

Because of a page limit for a report, I would like to decrease the linespread between individual `\item`s. I know this is generally not a good idea, but I really need the space.

How can I achieve this globally, say, with a couple of lines of code in the preamble?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `enumitem` package lets you set this globally. You can even specifiy a negative seperation between the items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[1]{itemsep=-5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \item Some
  \item Items
\item and distances
\end{itemize}

\setlist[1]{itemsep=-10pt}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Some
  \item Items
\item and distances
\end{itemize}

\setlist[1]{itemsep=50pt}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Some
  \item Items
\item and distances
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `nolistsep` option kills all extra spacing between items.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `itemize` environment you can use the `compactitem` environment of the package `paralist`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \item Some
 \item Items
 \item and distances
\end{itemize}

\begin{compactitem}
 \item Some
 \item Items
 \item and distances
\end{compactitem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I prefer [the answer by Martin H](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/reduce-linespread-between-item-globally/21189#21189) because in most documents I use the package `enumitem` to change the labels of lists and then it seems daft to load *another* package for manipulating lists.