# Extreme vertical spacing between list items & nested lists

Tags: lists, line-spacing

How can I fine tune and reduce the vertical spacing of list items and nested lists so characters from lines above and below are almost pixel-touching each other?

Example:

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

@egreg:

When I try:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,before*=\tighten,noitemsep]
\item List 1
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.,before*=\tighten,noitemsep]
\item Item Aabcg
\item Item Bagcb
\item Item Cabcg
\item Item Dagcb
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

there is a tall space between `List 1` and `Item Aabcg`

Can you further modify your answer to fix this?

**UPDATE 2:**

@egreg:

Thanks but I still get:

```
1. List 1

     A. Item Aabcg
     B. Item Bagcb
     C. Item Cabcg
     D. Item Dagcb
```

Can you get rid of that space between `List 1` and `Item Aabcg` to get:

```
1. List 1
     A. Item Aabcg
     B. Item Bagcb
     C. Item Cabcg
     D. Item Dagcb
```

Comment: See also [Reduce linespread between \item globally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/reduce-linespread-between-item-globally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/extreme-vertical-spacing-between-lines), here is a solution that preserves even distance between baselines.

```
\makeatletter
\let\tightset@fontsize\set@fontsize
\patchcmd\tightset@fontsize{#3}{#2}{}{}
\newcommand{\tighten}{\let\set@fontsize\tightset@fontsize
  \fontsize{\f@size}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont}
\makeatother
```

Then the list can be input as

```
\begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt]
\item List 1
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.,before*=\tighten,noitemsep,topsep=0pt]
  \item Item Aabcg
  \item Item Bagcb
  \item Item Cabcg
  \item Item Dagcb
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,enumitem}

\makeatletter
\let\tightset@fontsize\set@fontsize
\patchcmd\tightset@fontsize{#3}{#2}{}{}
\newcommand{\tighten}{\let\set@fontsize\tightset@fontsize
  \fontsize{\f@size}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt]
  \item List 1
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.,before*=\tighten,nolistsep,topsep=0pt]
    \item Item A
    \item Item B
    \item Item C
    \item Item D
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Checking the output with `\showbox` proves that the spacing is the same: between the "List 1" line and the "Item A" line, TeX inserts 3.16669pt glue, exactly the same as the glue inserted between the "Item A" and the "Item B" lines (and the others as well), which is right, since those lines have no descenders. The height of the "Item A" line is 6.83331pt, which added to 3.16669pt gives 10pt.

There might be a slight difference in a real document if `\topsep` in the inner list is not set to zero (the `nolistsep` key sets it to `0pt plus 0.1pt`), but not with the **article** class which does `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: Please check the UPDATE section of this original post.

Comment: The parameter to modify is `\parsep` in the outer list; however a "real life" example is needed to be sure.

Comment: tried `[parsep=0pt]` but the space between `1. List 1` and `A. Item Aabcg` is greater than the space between each item within the inner list.

Comment: On my computer the spaces appear the same.

Comment: Please check the UPDATE 2 section of this original post.

Comment: Hmm.. on your computer it's correct? That's odd... Can you write your complete script starting from preamble to the end so I can double-check my script? Maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) in order to tweak the item spacing in lists (either `enumerate` or `itemize`). The following example highlights some of the spacing needs you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
  \item List 1
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.,itemsep=-1ex,topsep=-2ex]
    \item Item A
    \item Item B
    \item Item C
    \item Item D
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,resume]
  \item List 2
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.]
    \item Item A
    \item Item B
    \item Item C
    \item Item D
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

...which looks like this:

[image: List spacing]

Read the `enumitem` package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) to see all the different settings that can be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the text lines touch each other, use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{nolistsep} % kills all vertical spacing
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\offinterlineskip % It's ugly, don't use it unless necessary
\begin{enumerate}
  \item List 1
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.]
    \item Item A
    \item Item B
    \item Item C
    \item Item D
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

It that is not what you want, you may want to delete `\offinterlineskip` as well as `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

You can increase `\lineskip` parameter after `\offinterlineskip` to set the space between line boxes. e.g.

```
\offinterlineskip
\setlength{\lineskip}{1pt}
```

For more information, see my answer in [your previous question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/extreme-vertical-spacing-between-lines)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. I want to start out with characters overlapping each other, then expand the vertical spacing to my liking. What parameter value should I tweak to increase the vertical spacing now that they are vertically squished?

Comment: Great, so just like my previous question, I'll just add `\lineskip=1pt` after `\offinterlineskip` and modify the value to my preferences. Thanks!